# Why do I get "undeclared name: any (requires version go1.18 or later)" when using any instead of interface{}? I am using Go 1.18

Tags: go, go-modules

When trying to use `any` instead of `interface{}` with the Go 1.18 toolchain, you can get the error:

```
undeclared name: any (requires version go1.18 or later)
```

Why is that, and how can you solve it? `any` was [introduced](https://go.dev/doc/go1.18#generics) in Go 1.18.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will get this error if your go.mod file lists a `go` version below 1.18, such as:

```
module example.com/foo

go 1.17
```

Changing your go.mod to instead read `go 1.18` should resolve the error.

In general, each module's go.mod file controls the version of the Go language that is used when compiling that module, which allows for a more gradual adoption of new language changes with each module author opting in at their own pace. This is described in more detail in the [Go language changes](https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/28221-go2-transitions.md#language-changes) design document.

Example of this error on the playground, including a go.mod file you can edit: https://go.dev/play/p/au6TtTvNsRy